# Notifications system android - Cannot resolve 'MID'

Tags: android, performance

I want to implement daily notifications for my app. I've got a problem with AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ActivitySplashScreen.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.diamond)
                .setContentTitle("Alarm Fired")
                .setContentText("Events To be PErformed").setSound(alarmSound)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        notificationManager.notify(MID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
        MID++;

    }

}
```

I'm getting: `Cannot resolve symbol "MID"`

Please help me guys! I've got this error for the first time

Answer (score 0):

MID mus be a unique Integer as I guess. 
You may try `(int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE)`

thiswill produce a unique Id for each notification

```
 notificationManager.notify((int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE), mNotifyBuilder.build());
```